# creating file type condition when uploading files in php

Tags: php

I am using this condition, but it's not working as it is always false i.e no file types meet the condition, so i fighre there must be an error in syntax but I can't figure it out.

```
if (!($_FILES["uploaded"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
&& (!$_FILES["uploaded"]["type"] == "video/flv")
&& (!$_FILES["uploaded"]["type"] == "video/webm" )
&& (!$_FILES["uploaded"]["type"] == "video/ogg" ))

{
   $message="not an accepted file format";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common case for [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array):

```
$type          = $_FILES["uploaded"]["type"];
$allowedTypes  = ["video/mp4", "video/flv", "video/webm", "video/ogg"];
$isRefusedType = !in_array($type, $allowedTypes);
if ($isRefusedType) {
    $message = "not an accepted file format";
}
```

Or [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) against a [*flipped array*](http://php.net/array_flip):

```
$type          = $_FILES["uploaded"]["type"];
$allowedTypes  = array_flip(["video/mp4", "video/flv", "video/webm", "video/ogg"]);
$isRefusedType = !isset($allowedTypes[$type]);
if ($isRefusedType) {
    $message = "not an accepted file format";
}
```

Comment: Yep, I'd definitely go for `in_array` myself.

Comment: Anything not to use a `switch`, eh? ;) The value here, is that the disallowed types can be loaded from configuration.

Comment: Yes both are pretty similar in this case. I first tended to write an `in_array` example but found array keys worth to show, too. `in_array` examples exist, but can't find it yet. - Okay, added and also seeing it was the wrong logic, not refused types, but allowed ones.

Answer (score 5):

```
if ( !($_FILES["uploaded"]["type"] == "video/mp4"
       || $_FILES["uploaded"]["type"] == "video/flv"
       || $_FILES["uploaded"]["type"] == "video/webm"
       || $_FILES["uploaded"]["type"] == "video/ogg") )
{
   $message="not an accepted file format";
}
```

I assume valid means any of these types, so you check for any of these (using `or`) and than negate it.

Comment: was typing this up when you posted +1

Comment: Shouldn't the `!` character be outside the parentheses?

Comment: no because then if it's not mp4 but it is flv then the message will come up

Comment: It was about the next lines `(!$_FILES["uploaded"]["type"] == "video/flv")`??

Comment: @cheesemacfly too many parentheses and negations (it's getting late...), I'll correct it...

Comment: @user1559811 I misread your parentheses and forgot to remove the `!`'s, please check the updated answer.

Comment: @jeroen looks better without the parentheses!

Answer (score 2):

Longer on a vertical scale, but in my opinion more readable.

```
switch ($_FILES["uploaded"]["type"]) {
    case "video/webm":
    case "video/mp4":
    case "video/flv":
    case "video/ogg":
        $message = "Okie dokie";
        break;
    default:
        $message = "Invalid format";
}
```